# Calculate the integral $\iiint_G(x+y + \sqrt{z})\,\mathrm{d} x\mathrm{d} y\mathrm{d} z$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate the integral 
>   $$\iiint_G(x+y + \sqrt{z})\,\mathrm{d} x\mathrm{d} y\mathrm{d} z$$
>   where $G$ is bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=1$, $z=x^2 + y^2$.

Please, give me some hints, how i must calculate this integral?

Comment: Maybe using cylindrical coordinate with
$$
\theta \in [0,\pi/2],\ r\in[0,1],\ z \in [r^2,1]
$$
(This is based on my quick mental representation of the graphs, I might be totally wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. $G$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded by the planes $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=1$, and by the [elliptic paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid#Elliptic_paraboloid) $z=x^2+y^2$. Hence
$$G:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\,:\, x\geq 0,\, y\geq 0,\, x^2+y^2\leq z\leq 1\}$$
Therefore, changing to cylindrical coordinates, $G$ is given by the conditions:
$$\rho\in [0,1],\, \theta \in [0,\pi/2],\, z \in [\rho^2,1].$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please, could you write multiple integral with boundaries?

Comment: I give the parametrization of $G$ in cylindrical coordinates, try to write the iterated integral.